# How to run docker container as privileged within Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, docker-privileged

I have a docker container that needs to run with --privileged to establish a VPN connection once it boots up

I am migrating it into Cloud Run using Cloud Build

I tried --container-privileged but that seems to only work for GCE, I also added the following to the `args` for the `gcloud run deploy` call in the cloudbuild.yaml but it complains with `error: "Invalid command \"docker run --privileged\": file not found anywhere in PATH`

```
   - --command
    - docker run --privileged
```

Comment: Google Cloud Run does not use Docker to run containers. Cloud Run uses gVisor. Cloud Run does not support privileged containers.

Answer (score 6):

Google Cloud Run does not use Docker to run containers.
Cloud Run uses gVisor.
Cloud Run does not support privileged containers.